# Undeclared StorageMetadata when simulating on real device

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on an app that has an extension of Firebase's `StorageMetadata`. It compiles and runs normally when I run it on any of the simulators, but when I try to simulate the app on a real device, I get the errors `Use of undeclared type StorageMetadata` and `Use of undeclared type StorageReference`.

Has anyone been through this or has any idea of what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't figure out why it only happened when running the app on a real device, but I just replaced the Pods folder for a previous checkout and ir worked.